# Best way for IROBOT Roomba 960 to "climb" 26mm step

Tags: roomba

We got a IROBOT Roomba 960 for our new apartment. The apartment has however in one door frame there's a step of about 26mm (roughly 1 inch).

What's the best way for the Roomba to overcome this obstacle. I was thinking about building a small ramp. Is there a better/easier way to achieve this (except for lifting it manually to the other room)? If not, what angle should I use for the ramp, that the Roomba will be able to climb it on it's own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a different vac robot brand ilife v7 we use a piece of wood (floor panel) which is 8mm thick.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Wojciech. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. One-line answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.